# ReactJS: Uncaught error: Cannot find module '@progress/kendo-scheduler-react-wrapper'

Tags: reactjs

![kendo ui npm error]https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cERD.jpg

I keep getting a can't resolve error message while trying to implement this kendo-ui

Comment: Please show your code, your package.json etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to install Kendo package.

```
$ npm install --save @progress/kendo-scheduler-react-wrapper
```

cf: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/wrappers/scheduler/